# Convert string to a json object

Tags: android, json, servlets

I want to create json object from a string that comes as a response from a servlet in my server.

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url,String a) {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("branchname", a));

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();          

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }


        return jObj;            
}}
```

This is my servlet..

```
public class AvailabilityResponse extends HttpServlet {

@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

        String br_id;
        br_id=request.getParameter("branchname");

    try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888  /atmlivedetails","root","root");  
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select atmbrno, atmbrname  from location_stat where act_brname='"+br_id+"'");
        int i=0;
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
        while(rs.next()){

    String s = rs.getString("atmbrno");
    String t = rs.getString("atmbrname");

    JSONObject arrayObj = new JSONObject();

    arrayObj.put("atmbrno",s);
    arrayObj.put("atmbrname",t);

    jArray.add(i,arrayObj);
    i++;
    }
    rs.close ();
    st.close ();
    out.print(jArray);
}

    catch(Exception e){
            out.print(e);
    }


}}
```

but when I run this it says Error

```
"parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"atmbrname":"ANURADAPURA
[ATM 2]","atmbrno":"ATM084"},{"atmbrname":"MANNAR BRANCH  
","atmbrno":"ATM344"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted
to JSONObject"
```

what is the wrong in this case?

Here is my calling class

```
public class ListAtmActivity extends ListActivity{

private static String url ="http://10.0.2.2:8080/hello/AvailabilityResponse";

//TextView error;
//String brName;

//Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
//String brName = b.getString("key");

private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String ATM_NO = "atmbrno";
private static final String ATM_PLACE = "atmbrname";

// contacts JSONArray
//JSONArray contacts = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

    String brName=getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");


    /*Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    brName = b.getString("key");
    */


    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url,brName);


    try{
        //String results;
        JSONArray contacts = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);

        for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
            JSONObject json_data = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

            // Storing each json item in variable
            String atm_id = json_data.getString(ATM_NO);
            String atm_name = json_data.getString(ATM_PLACE);

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(ATM_NO, atm_id);
            map.put(ATM_PLACE, atm_name);

            contactList.add(map);                
        }                       
    }

    catch(JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
   ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_main,
            new String[] { ATM_NO, ATM_PLACE }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name , R.id.email });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

}}
```

Comment: because you are sending a json array just change the json object lines to json array all operations are allowed or else aadan{ in front and} in end of the retrieved string it will doo

Comment: I think the problem comes with return array from servlet..it may not according to correct format..but i can't get what's the wrong?

Comment: @droidhot- can u correct that wrong..i can't get it..

Comment: there is no problem at all the return is an array not an object either use an jsonarray instead of json object or add opening and closing braces to the array so it becomes an object refer w3schools for further details on json

Comment: [{"atmbrname":"ANURADAPURA
[ATM 2]","atmbrno":"ATM084"},{"atmbrname":"MANNAR BRANCH  
","atmbrno":"ATM344"}] this is an array to make it an object { [{"atmbrname":"ANURADAPURA
[ATM 2]","atmbrno":"ATM084"},{"atmbrname":"MANNAR BRANCH  
","atmbrno":"ATM344"}]} change to this

Comment: @droidhot- how to add opening and closing braces to it.. this will be a big help me..please..

Comment: jObj = new JSONObject("{"+json+"}"); this should do the trick ;)
or you can go for the bellow answer its also right and would work

Comment: After that change it says this error: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Names must be strings, but [{"atmbrname":"ANURADAPURA [ATM 2]      ","atmbrno":"ATM008"},{"atmbrname":"MANNAR BRANCH            ","atmbrno":"ATM044"}] is of type org.json.JSONArray at character 124 of {[{"atmbrno":"ATM008","atmbrname":"ANURADAPURA [ATM 2]      "},{"atmbrno":"ATM044","atmbrname":"MANNAR BRANCH            "}]

Comment: where is the closing braces try understanding json in detail (and mannar? is int it near nairsamajam school u frm thr?)

Comment: its best you shift it to json array itself you can do all operations on a json array as json object reffer w3schools json it explains well on json

Comment: Names must be strings eror sujest parsing that is not done in this class where is the parsing class

Comment: OK..Thanks..I'll try with Json Array

Comment: @droidhot- I added my othe class to this quwstion above..check it.

Comment: you dont have a json array named contacts ofcourse then it will throw an error go for the json array and you wont need to fetch a json array from json object can directly impliment it

Comment: JSONArray contacts = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url,brName);
and make sure you go for the json array type class described in the 1 st answer

Comment: I can't get this..can u please do the chage and post here..I'm very new to Android..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change json object to json array,

```
  public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONArray jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

    public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url,String a) {

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("branchname", a));

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();          

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON Array
        try {
            jObj = new JSONArray(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }


        return jObj;            
}}
```

Your return data is json array, but you convert json object ,that's only Exception raise.

```
  static JSONArray jObj = null;

   // try parse the string to a JSON Array
    try {
        jObj = new JSONArray(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

as per your request posting

```
   public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
     static JSONArray jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

     // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

  }

public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url,String a) {

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("branchname", a));

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();          

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONArray(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }


    return jObj;            
   }}
```

and in the parsing class

```
 public class ListAtmActivity extends ListActivity{

 private static String url ="http://10.0.2.2:8080/hello/AvailabilityResponse";

 //TextView error;
  //String brName;

   //Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
 //String brName = b.getString("key");

private static final String TAG_CONTACTS = "contacts";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String ATM_NO = "atmbrno";
 static final String ATM_PLACE = "atmbrname";

 // contacts JSONArray
  //JSONArray contacts = null;

    @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

String brName=getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");


/*Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
brName = b.getString("key");
*/


// Hashmap for ListView
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

// Creating JSON Parser instance
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

// getting JSON string from URL
 JSONArray contacts = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url,brName);


try{
    //String results;


    for(int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++){
        JSONObject json_data = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

        // Storing each json item in variable
        String atm_id = json_data.getString(ATM_NO);
        String atm_name = json_data.getString(ATM_PLACE);

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map.put(ATM_NO, atm_id);
        map.put(ATM_PLACE, atm_name);

        contactList.add(map);                
    }                       
}

catch(JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}

  /**
   * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
   * */
  ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
        R.layout.list_main,
        new String[] { ATM_NO, ATM_PLACE }, new int[] {
                R.id.name , R.id.email });

   setListAdapter(adapter);

   }}
```

Comment: It works...Thank You very much..No errors but still that Listview not happens..I have to work with that..!

Answer (score 0):

you need JsonArray to parse the getting String , basically you get JsonArray in your Response.

```
JSONArray jObj = null;

   // try parse the string to a JSON Array
    try {
        jObj = new JSONArray(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
```